# ReferenceError: params is not defined

Tags: javascript, x-editable

I am trying to implement an inline bubble editing in my data table...

I would like to implement it in many place. So I would like to create a global function. The following code is working fine:

```
"fnDrawCallback":function(){
    $('#data_table_list td').editable({
        params: function(params) {
            var pk = $(this).data('pk');
            var name = $(this).data('name');
            var data = {};
            data['field'] = name;
            data['value'] = params.value;
            data['id'] = pk;
            data['slug'] = slug;
            return data;
        },
        url: "{% url 'request_access' %}",
            success : function(data) {
            if (data.status == true) {
                toastr.success(data.msg);
            }
            else {
                toastr.error(data.msg);
            }
         },
         error: function () {
             toastr.error('Something went wrong');
         }
    });
},
```

But I have tried the following code to implement as a global function.

In my `core.js` file:

```
function python(params)
{
    var pk = $(this).data('pk');
    var name = $(this).data('name');
    var data = {};
    data['field'] = name;
    data['value'] = params.value;
    data['id'] = pk;
    data['slug'] = slug;
    return data;
}
```

And in my HTML page:

```
"fnDrawCallback":function(){
    $('#data_table_list td').editable({
        params: python(params),
        url: "{% url 'request_access' %}",
            success : function(data) {
            if (data.status == true) {
                toastr.success(data.msg);
            }
            else {
                toastr.error(data.msg);
            }
         },
         error: function () {
             toastr.error('Something went wrong');
         }
    });
},
```

But it shows an error:

> ReferenceError: `params is not defined`

How can I create a global function?

Comment: You want `params: python,` without the `()`

Comment: It's working ....But I want to inform you that I need to pass the slug variable to the python function ....

Comment: @Phil could you help me to pass a variable to the function  if we are not using paranthesis

Comment: Your `python` function doesn't accept a `slug` argument. You should change it to `function python(params, slug) { ... }`. Then try `params: params => python(params, slug),`

Comment: @Phil if I pass I like that it again shows ReferenceError: params is not defined

I am only define the "params" at here params => python(params, slug)

Comment: @Phil my core.js like this no

function python(params,slug)
{

}

And my html script like this 

params: python(params,slug),

Comment: That's completely different to what's in my comment. I suggest you read it again closely